# VB.net convert , to decimal (order of placement)

Tags: vb.net, decimal

Hi I have a textbox which dose some math calculations perfect if you work with decimals not so if you work with commas.. the first option i explored was to just accept numbers and decimals in a masked textbox... but why? some of us have learned to use commas since we first started school... so my idea is to have a textbox which searches for commas and turns them into decimals for the user.

I have the following code but as example if I type in 2,5 my conversion becomes 25. so yes i have converted the comma to decimal but have lost its placing. The question thus being how can I do my conversion properly with the right decimal placement?

```
If TextBox13.Text.Contains(",") Then
TextBox13.Text = Replace(TextBox13.Text, ",", ".")
dim test as double textbox1.text
msgbox(test)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make comma an illegal entry. Don't you block entering letters anyway.

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    e.Handled = SingleDecimal(sender, e.KeyChar)
End Sub

Public Function SingleDecimal(sender As System.Object, eChar As Char) As Boolean
    Dim chkstr As String = "0123456789."
    If chkstr.IndexOf(eChar) > -1 OrElse eChar = Constants.vbBack Then
        If eChar = "." Then
            If DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text.IndexOf(eChar) > -1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Other solution maybe is replacing comma with dot in string and then passing it back to textbox.

```
If TextBox13.Text.Contains(",") Then
dim tempStr as string = TextBox13.Text
TextBox13.Text = Replace(tempStr, ",", ".")
dim test as double textbox1.text
msgbox(test)
End If
```

And anyway shouldn't this be written this way:

```
TextBox13.Text = tempStr.Replace(",", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cast the string to decimal or double?

> Dim test as Decimal = CDec(textbox1.Text)
>    Or Dim test as Double= CDbl(textbox1.Text)